# registerForActivityResult() outside onCreate() with Compose

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

So I am trying to launch the intent `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. I first tried with `startActivityForResult` but I noticed it was depreciated so I tried to find another way to do this. So I found the `registerForActivityResult` method but it turns out it must run after onCreate() has finished :

> Note: While it is safe to call registerForActivityResult() before your fragment or activity is created, you cannot launch the ActivityResultLauncher until the fragment or activity's Lifecycle has reached CREATED.

Since I am using Jetpack Compose and setContent is in onCreate() my Activity has actually never finished creating because all my Composables functions are run in the setContent of my MainActivity

So how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the latest version of activity-compose you can use [**`rememberLauncherForActivityResult()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#rememberlauncherforactivityresult) to register a request to `Activity#startActivityForResult`.

Something like:

```
val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
    result.value = it
}

Button(onClick = { launcher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf")) }) {
    Text(text = "Open Document")
}

result.value?.let {
   //...
}
```

Comment: To Android Studio `result.value` is undefined reference

Comment: @ScarySneer Did you add:  `val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }`?  `result` is a `MutableState<Uri?>`.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry, actually `result` is defined, what android studio complains about is `value`. The actual error is Undefined reference: value

Comment: So turns out it's my fault, instead of using `val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }` I used `val result by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }`. So now I am wondering what is the difference between these two since in [compose docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) they say "These declarations are equivalent, and are provided as syntax sugar for different uses of state"